# Unsatisfiedlinkerror when application started from cron

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, jboss, cron, java-native-interface

I've got a web application written in Java and deployed on JBoss. The application is hosted of an EC2 instance of Amazon's cloud. When I login as the user 'Ubuntu' onto my server and start the JBoss server, my application is able to access the JNI libraries (which are also installed on the same EC2 machine) just fine.

However, I needed to write a script that would automatically restart the jboss server every night so I wrote a script and put it on the crontab of the server. When I was logged in as the user 'Ubuntu' and added my script to 'crontab -e', it didn't even execute. However, when I edited the crontab logged in as root, that worked (I edited the /etc/crontab file and specified that the user 'Ubuntu' should start the script). The script works fine and the server restarts fine every night. However, my application keeps getting 'UnsatisfiedLinkErrors' when it tries to access the JNI libraries. Strangely enough, this doesn't happen when I manually start the server logged in as the 'Ubuntu' user. Any ideas how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to play with LD_LIBRARY_PATH settings for your cron based script.

Java (JBoss) will look for your native library inside LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Make sure to add your lib into LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Alternatively you can specify the location via java.library.path.

```
-Djava.library.path=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${LOCATION_OF_YOUR_LIB}
```